# TSQL: How do I search for a grade within a list of grades?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I search for a grade within a list of grades?  Some grades are of string data type, for example 'PK', and 'KK'.

The production list has over a thousand students each in different grade levels, so I'm not sure how to ensure the query would address that.

The logic I'm trying for is something like  WHERE CurrentGrade like ('%SchoolGrades%').

**Example query results:**

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

*(I didn't design the tables I have to work with as I know they are not optimal, but it's what I have to work with, thanks for the help.)*

**Sample code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #StudentGrades(
       StudentID int
  , CurrentGrade varchar(255)
  , SchoolEarliestGrade varchar(255)
  , SchoolID int
  , School varchar(255)
  , SchoolGrades varchar(255)
  )

 INSERT INTO #StudentGrades (StudentID, CurrentGrade, SchoolEarliestGrade, SchoolID, School, SchoolGrades)
 VALUES
(7777777,   11, 'PK'    , 111   ,'Smith Elementary' ,'PK, KK, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05'),
(7777777,   11, '06'    , 222   ,'Jones Middle' ,'06, 07, 08'),
(7777777,   11, '09'    , 333   ,'Perez High School'    ,'09, 10, 11, 12')

SELECT * FROM #StudentGrades
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the rows where the CurrentGrade is in the SchoolGrades.

```
SELECT *
FROM StudentGrades
WHERE ', ' + SchoolGrades + ', ' LIKE '%, ' + CurrentGrade + ', %'
```

Edit: This is the best solution with help from the comments. Thanks, all.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @scsimon Yup.  I think that's what OP was asking for, but had the logic backwards?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks @justiceorjustus.  Thanks to all who responded, I wasn't exactly sure how to ask this question logically.

Comment: Please Note: this will return value if CurrentGrade = 11 and SchoolGrade = '10, 12,113'

Comment: @JM1 No problem! Just to note, I did notice that CurrentGrade is an int and SchoolGrades can have 'PK' and 'KK'... so you'll never find 'PK' and 'KK' as CurrentGrade.

Comment: @PawelCz Noted... let me know if you think my edit covers that.

Comment: @justiceorjustus. Yeap, much better now :-) upvoted.

Comment: Typically avoiding the issues like "11" matching "113" is by wrapping both strings with separators: `where ',' + SchoolGrades + ',' like '%,' + CurrentGrade + ',%'`. Your second query doesn't solve the problem, e.g. the first term will cheerfully match "11" to "311".

Comment: @HABO Good point. I edited my answer and will be using that solution in the future for myself, as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fatc that the grades are in string field you can use `like`

```
 select * from StudentGrades 
 where schoolGrades like '%11%';
```

or

```
 select * from StudentGrades 
 where schoolGrades like '%KK%';
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge, how could I make this work if there are a thousand students, each in a different grade and from various schools?  Something like WHERE CurrentGrade like ('%SchoolGrades%')?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from StudentGrades 
 where schoolGrades like '%KK%' OR schoolGrades like '%PK%';
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use a recursive CTE to unpivot the data in, separated values of SchoolGrades.   Then derrive the needed values, and fianally use a simple where clause in the select against the CTE.  Not sure of performance as the recursive loop is a record by record approach; however it may be faster than a full table scan with 2 ors.

Working example:

http://rextester.com/NAB12900

1. strCTE gets the values to normalize the data for us
2. subcte provides the the needed grades on individual rows with data normalized
3. and the last query simply limits to only current grade matching stringvalue.

.

```
WITH StrCTE AS
(
  SELECT  1 start, CHARINDEX(',' , schoolGrades) stop, StudentID, CurrentGrade, SchoolEarliestGrade, SchoolID, School, SchoolGrades
  FROM#studentGrades A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  stop + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,schoolgrades  , stop + 1), StudentID, CurrentGrade, SchoolEarliestGrade, SchoolID, School, SchoolGrades
  FROM StrCTE A
  WHERE stop > 0
),
SUBCTE AS (SELECT StudentID, CurrentGrade, SchoolEarliestGrade, SchoolID, School, SchoolGrades, ltrim(SUBSTRING(schoolgrades , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END)) AS stringValue
           FROM StrCTE)
SELECT * 
FROM SUBCTE
WHERE currentgrade = stringValue
```

IMO this strCTE query gives you the ability to normalize the data allowing other standard SQL queries to function.  Maybe create STRCTE as a materialized view on which your analysis is done.  as the materialized view can have indexes which reduce the performance loss from the recursive loop.